# firebase web or react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, react-native-firebase

I'm building a React Native app with Firebase for backend, and I couldn't find good information to help me decide if I should go with the official firebase web library, or react-native-firebase.

[This article from Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html) says

> "With the updates in the 3.1.0 SDK, almost all of the JavaScript SDK’s functionality should now work smoothly in React Native"

but at the [react-native-firebase github docs](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase), it says

> The Web SDK doesn't support many of Firebase's services.

Normally I would decide to go with the official Firebase Web SDK, but I see there's many people that complain about it, so I'm not sure what to do. Any advice/help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which features of firebase you are going to use with react native?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya not sure at this point, that's why I want to go with the one that provides more Firebase's services.

Comment: In that case you should go with react-native-firebase because it is using native library to give support in react native, so you will be getting almost everything

Comment: @RaviRupareliya thank you for the quick answer. Does the fact that I'm using Expo matter?

Comment: @hms with expo you'll have to eject to ExpoKit and add the modules you need starting from https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-firebase-app (they're react-native-firebase but reworked for Expo specifically)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience react-native-firebase is very good. There are very few things you can't do that you could do with the web version and the maintainers are very helpful.

My only complaint is that unit testing is very difficult/impossible. If you intend to test your app properly you will be limited to integration tests with something like detox.